# I don't know why my Writerow() is reading each character in a list as a separate data element

Tags: python-3.x, csv, export-to-csv

I have a list `result` that contains my data. 
For example:

```
result =  ['This is first | element', 'This is second | element', 'This is third | element']
```

I'm exporting this into a csv file using Writerow() with the below code:

```
import csv

with open('names.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    filewriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter='|', quotechar='\"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    for i in range(len(result)):
        filewriter.writerow(result[i])
    csvfile.flush()
    csvfile.close()
```

But surprisingly this is exporting my list as follows:

```
T|h|i|s| i|s| f|i|r|s|t|"|"|e|l|e|m|e|n|t|
T|h|i|s| i|s| s|e|c|o|n|d|"|"|e|l|e|m|e|n|t|
T|h|i|s| i|s| t|h|i|r|d|"|"|e|l|e|m|e|n|t|
```

I have no idea why this is happening. Can someone please tell me why this is happening and how to rectify this? What did I do wrong in my code?

Comment: writerow expects a list but you are passing a string. Check my answer below on how to fix it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strings can be interpreted as lists in python. The function writewrow expects a list as input, where each element of the list is one column of the csv file. The string elements of you result list are therefore interpreted as lists with each character representing a column.

You could wrap each string in an extra list like that:

```
result =  [['This is first | element'], ['This is second | element'], ['This is third | element']]
```

Which gives you:

```
"This is first | element"
"This is second | element"
"This is third | element"
```

Hope thats what you want.

Answer (score 0):

[csvwriter.writerow](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.csvwriter.writerow) expected a list as an input.
So when you write `This is first | element`, the data is converted to `['T', 'h', 'i', 's', ' ', 'i', 's', ' ', 'f', 'i', 'r', 's', 't', ' ', '|', ' ', 'e', 'l', 'e', 'm', 'e', 'n', 't']` and that is reflected in the csv.

You would need to wrap each element in your list inside another list, so the resultant list will be `[['This is first | element'], ['This is second | element'], ['This is third | element']]`, which you can write to the csv.

The code will then change to .

```
result =  ['This is first | element', 'This is second | element', 'This is third | element']
#Convert result to list of lists
li = [[item] for item in result]

import csv

with open('file.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    filewriter = csv.writer(csvfile)
    #Write each list to csv
    for item in li:
        filewriter.writerow(item)
    csvfile.flush()
    csvfile.close()
```

You can also get rid of the for loop by using [csvwriter.writerows](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.csvwriter.writerows) as follows.

```
result =  ['This is first | element', 'This is second | element', 'This is third | element']
li = [[item] for item in result]

import csv

with open('file.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    filewriter = csv.writer(csvfile)
    filewriter.writerows(li)
    csvfile.flush()
    csvfile.close()
```

In both cases, the csv will be:

```
This is first | element
This is second | element
This is third | element
```